# AWS Athena deployment serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless, amazon-athena

has somebody a hint how I have to transform !Ref und !Sub from CloudFormation into serverless.yml.

```
resources:
  Resources:
    AthenaCreateDatabaseQuery:
      Type: 'AWS::Athena::NamedQuery'
      Properties:
        Description: Run this query to initialize the Athena database
        QueryString: "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $(self:custom.etlDatabase};"
        Database: ${self:custom.etlDataBase}
```

- In Cloudformation the QueryString Property starts with !Sub and 
  the Database Property with !Ref.

Thanks Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

!Sub isn't currently supported natively by serverless.com ([see this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3184)) but you can use the following plugin https://gitlab.com/kabo/serverless-cf-vars

> Whenever you want the cloudformation template to have a string that contains ${}, simply use #{} instead, and it will get transformed into correct ${} (with Fn::Sub inserted for you) in the cloudformation template before deployment.

Or use a custom variable syntax as suggested [here](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3184#issuecomment-304671007). Both require the use of Fn::Sub and Fn::Ref in yaml instead of the short form !Sub and !Ref

Comment: Thanks, but when it comes to a multiline create table statement which is in cloudformation introduced by  !Sub > I got again lost.